# Regex excluding

Tags: regex

I have a list of strings:

```
foo001
foo003
foo004
foo005
foo006
.
.
.
foo010
foo011
foo012
foo013
```

I want a regex expression that matches everything except for foo001.

^foo00[3-9] is not enough (leaves foo010, foo011...)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Which language? [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html)? [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)? [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)? [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php)? [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^foo(?!001$)\d+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/10

The `negative lookahead` will disallow `001`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!foo001$).+
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use anchors `^` and `$` to test individual values or using `Multiline` option if they are placed on separate lines in text, and a negative lookahead:

`^(?!foo0{2}1).+$`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cW8fW1/3)